# cocos2d-iphone jsb & cocos2d-html5 compatibility: ctor, init, associateWithNative

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone, cross-platform

I'm writing a cross-platform game with cocos2d (iphone jsb + cocos2d-html5) and I'm wondering how to actually make it cross-platform. Code that would work with -html5 won't necessarily work with -iphone jsb and vice versa.

Currently I'm stuck at the following (related) questions:

1. What's the difference between `ctor` and `init`?
2. When should I overload `ctor`, and when should I overload `init`?
3. When I should I call `_super()` from `ctor` and/or `init`?
4. When should I call `.init()` from `ctor` if I overload do `ctor`?
5. How should I instantiate objects? With `var inst = new Obj(); inst.init();`? Or just `var inst = new Obj();`? I understand there are `.create()` methods which make sense, but I'm asking in the case of me writing my own `create` methods.
6. When should I use `associateWithNative`?

I had some code that worked with the html5 version, but then I got an error saying the object was already initialized on the iPhone jsb version, so clearly I was getting something wrong. I've tried look at the MoonWarriors code but it seems to never use `associateWithNative`, which I thought was required, and it sometimes overloads `ctor`, sometimes not, sometimes calls `init` from the `ctor`, sometimes not, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's hard to find the way out too, I have the same problem, I developed the game mostly testing on browser & now I also have lots of issues & cannot port it to iOS,.

As far as your question goes:

1. `ctor` calls constructor for the class, `init` initializes the new object.
2. You should overload `ctor` when subclassing, `init` when doing custom initialization behavior for the object of the class your
   subclassing.
3. I'd say always, although I also noticed that this is not everywhere present at the MoonWarriors demo.
4. I think that's not a good practice.
5. `var inst = new Obj();` & then `inst.init()` or the other way is to call `var inst = Obj.create();`
6. `associateWithNative` should be called in `ctor`

About creating objects from a class you've created, e.g. if you have a `var Warrior` which has `_hp` as a private property & you want to assign it at creation, there are 3 ways as far as I understood:

1.With Constructor:

```
var myWarrior = new Warrior(hp);
```

& then you set the `_hp` in the constructor `ctor:function(hp)..`

2.With Initialization:

```
var myWarrior = new Warrior();
myWarrior.init(hp);
```

& then you set the `_hp` in the initialization `init:function(hp)..`

3.With Factory Method:

```
var myWarrior = Warrior.create(hp);
```

& then you set the `_hp` in the create method which would be after the declaration of the `var Warrior` & it will create a new object & initialize it properly.

EDIT: Also starting from cocos2d-iphone-2.1-rc2 you'll no longer need to override `ctor` in order to place `associateWithNative` since from that build on that call is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

`ad 1-5.` 
I've found out that overwriting ctor - even though might seem more convenient especially for somebody coming from JS world at the moment might cause problems when compiling cocos2d-js code on other platforms - if you stumble on `ERROR in *: Invalid Proxy object` error it might be because of the overwriting the ctor method (was in few cases for me). Also sometimes constructor methods on native classes will expect parameters that you overwrite/handle on your end for classes that inherit from native classes and it might cause some conflicts as well.

Apart of that all the differences were described by Kex - I'd say looking at provided samples and cocos2d source the safest and "Cocos2d way" would be to use combination of init methods and static factory `create`.

`ad 6.` 
It is no longer required to use the `associateWithNative` method (you can read more here: [cocos2d-js-devel](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocos2d-js-devel/yYxZLXm4aLs))